# Custom Precompiler For Certain Extensions Only

Tags: texstudio

Is there a way to configure the Texstudio build process so that a custom precompile command is run only for files with a certain extension? In other words, if the extension is .gtex I want the build process to be:

foo.gtex --precompile--> foo.tex --xelatex--> foo.pdf

But if it's just .tex it should be:

foo.tex --xelatex--> foo.pdf

I've successfully set up the command run the precompiler in the configuration screen and it works, but it tries to run the precompiler on every build, not just .gtex files.

Comment: I'm not sure what your precompiler does exactly (is it some kind of templating engine?) but maybe you can handle the file check in some function inside the precompiler, i.e., if the extension is `.tex`, the precompiler runs but does nothing, it it is `.gtex` then the actual precompiling is done.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. I was able to make that work but I would still be interested to know if there is any more general way to make Texstudio's build system handle this.